# Linked list code giving correct answer, but bringing up error message saying program has 'stopped working'

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was working on a homework assignment with linked lists, and while it seems that the code itself is spitting out the "right" answer (what the teacher wants it to), it brings up an error message when running that states "the program has stopped working (it will be forced closed, reported to windows, etc)". The program *doesn't* force close after closing this dialogue, and besides this, seems to be exactly what my teacher is looking for in the assignment. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>    // Provides cout
#include <cstdlib>     // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
using namespace std;   // Allows all standard library items to be used

struct node
{ 
   int data;
   node* link;
};


void insert_at_head(node*& head, int entry) 
//Precondition:  head is the head pointer of a linked list, entry is
//               a non-negative integer
//Postcondition: Inserts a new node with data field set to entry at the 
//               beginning of the linked list head
{
  node* n;

  n = new node;
  n->data = entry;
  n->link = head;
  head = n;
}

void print(const node* head)
//Precondistion: head is the head pointer of a linked list
//Postcondition: Prints that linked list 
{
   const node* cursor; 

   cout << "The linked list is:" << endl;
   for (cursor=head; cursor != NULL; cursor=cursor->link) 
          cout << cursor-> data << " ";

   cout << endl; 

}


void delete_last(node* & head)
{
    while (head->link != NULL)
    {   
        int i;
        for(i = 0; 10 >= i; i++)
        {
        struct node* secondlast = head;
        struct node* last = head->link;
        while(last->link != NULL)
        {   struct node* t = last;
            secondlast = t;
            last = last->link;
        }
        delete last;
        secondlast->link = NULL;
        cout << "I have deleted the last element in the linked list" << endl;
        print(head);
        }
    }
    while (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
}

int main( )
{   int i;     
  node* head;

  head = NULL;


       for(i = 1; 10 >= i; i++)
       {
        insert_at_head(head, i);
       }

  print(head);
  delete_last(head);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That message is typically one you get when the program has crashed. To catch the crash "in action" you need to run in a debugger, then you can see where the crash happens, walk up the function call stack to your code (if it's not already there) and examine the values of variables. All to help you locate and figure out the reason for the crash.

Comment: I have to say, though, that all those loops in the `delete_last` function seems really suspect. Especially since you don't do enough checking for null-pointers. All that seems like *undefined behavior* waiting to happen, and one of the outcomes of undefined behavior is to seemingly work well.

Comment: There are three loops too many in `delete_last`. The only one that should be there is the innermost one.